# Maven dependencies - подключить зависимости в Web project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-ee, maven

Есть веб проект. Необходимо подключить зависимости. Intellij Idea автоматически генерит файл pom.xml.
В готовый файл добавляю следующий код:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Все, что между тегами красным - dependency not found.
Подскажите, в чем проблема?

Comment: Зависимостей не хватает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Была однажды аналогичная проблема в Intellij. Выяснилось, что в окне Maven Project справа сотрудник хотел нажать на кнопку "Toggle 'Skip Tests' Mode" но промазал и нажал на соседнюю кнопку "Toggle 'Offline' Mode". Полагаю, что у вас случилость то же самое или просто проблемы с сетью и внешнии репозитории недоступны.